# Why didn't a new kernel get installed on a Dell XPS 13?

Tags: drivers, kernel, dell, xps

I recently upgraded to 19.10 on a Dell XPS 13, which I recently purchased with Ubuntu already installed.

I thought that 19.10 was supposed to ship with the 5.3.x kernel but when I run `uname -r` I get `4.15.0-1059-oem`.

Is this a special kernel that is shipped by Dell? Is there some setting on my computer that isn't letting it update to the new kernel?

I'm thinking that the mismatch is causing problems - e.g., my wifi isn't working and when I try to run modprobe to load the drivers, it tells me there's an `Exec format error`, which I read is a sign that there's a kernel problem.

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact problem (XPS 13 with no wifi working after updating to 19.0/19.10) and the kernel was stuck on 4.15 just like in default Dell OEM 18.04. The solution is pretty simple:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
```

and then reboot (and make sure you boot in the new kernel, it should be the default behavior anyway). This fixed for me and after a quick check no other HW got broken in process :)